# get child node by name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get all children of a html tag with a certain name?

Let's assume I have a `<div>` which looks like this

```
<div id=test>
    <input name=test1/>
    <input name=test2/>
</div>
```

if I have the div element, how can I get any child with name test1 or test2? I tried

```
div.getElementsByName('test1')
```

but that does not work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`document.querySelector('input[name="test1"]')`

Or if you want to target a specific child of a specific element:

```
var test = document.querySelector('#test')
var test1 = test.querySelector('input[name="test1"]');
window.console.log(test1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Option #1:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("test1");
```

Option #2:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='test1']");
```

In both cases you'll get array as a response: x[0], x[1], ...

> div.getElementsByName('test1')

doesn't work because getElementsByName is a method of document object, you may only call document.getElementsByName('elementName').

Answer (score 3):

#### Your initial code didn't work because the name attributes in your html were not encased in quotes. They should be:

```
<div id=test>
  <input name="test1" />
  <input name="test2" />
</div>
```

*Be aware, that [**`getElementsByName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a live NodeList of matching elements which is an array-like object even if you expect and receive one result.*

---

#### If you would like to receive only one element rather than an array containing one element I've provided a couple of alternatives below:

> **USING THE `id` ATTRIBUTE:** If you know your name will be *unique in the **whole** document*, I'd advise using an `id` instead of the the
>   name or class attributes. Doing so would allow this:
>
> Html:
>
> ```
> <div id=test>
>   <input id="test1" name="test1"/> 
>   <input id="test2" name="test2"/> 
> </div>
> ```
>
> JavaScript:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("test1");
> ```

> **USING** [**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) :
>
> If you still need to use the name attribute then you can use
>   [**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)  with the following selection
>   parameter:
>
> ```
> document.querySelector('div > input[name="test1"]')
> ```
>
> [**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first element in the
>   document that matches the selection parameter.
>
> In the example above it says, return the first element that is an
>   `input` with name attribute equal to "test1" that is a child of a
>   `div`.

Comment: HTML does not require quotes around attribute values (it's a good practice, but it isn't required).  He doesn't have a space between the attribute value and the ending slash, though, which is required in this case.  You also seem to have missed the question; he's asking about trying to do div.getElementsByName, which doesn't work (it has to be document.getElementsByName).

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` with an attribute selector and a substring match if you want to get any tag with a value that contains a partial match.

```
var tags = document.querySelectorAll('*[name*="test"]');
console.log(tags);
```